# How to create JWK with node-jose from AES key represented as hex binary

Tags: node.js, security, jwt, jwe

I'm reading a [node-jose](https://github.com/cisco/node-jose) documentation which explains how to import a JWK key.
What I cant understand is how could I import and existing AES key from hexBinary format to create a `JWK.Key` instance?

For example, this is my AES key represented as hexBinary:

```
5A611871C939AB2432F0C0552315429D787DF69F7321B4810ED2E4363FF4A036
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. The problem was in the fact that `node-jose` creates `JWE.KEY` instance in which the key value is `Base64` encoded. So I had to translate my key from `hexBinary` representation to `Base64` encoded representation.

Comment: Any more information on this? I'm confused as to what you did here. A small code snippet will help